# Passing $_POST from view to model in MVC

Tags: php, mvc

I am building my own MVC structured project to learn the concepts of MVC and I need to pass $_POST variables from my view (which is a login form) to the model. Down below is my approach but I wonder if it is the correct way to do it or there is a better one for example passing it into the construct or maybe putting $_POST inside an array.. What do you think?

The `login` method is to generate a token for my login form in the `view` which is for the cookie

```
class Users
{    

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->db = Database::instance();
    }

    public function login()
    {
        return self::genToken();        
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        $username   = $_POST['username'];
        $password   = $_POST['password'];
        $rememberMe = $_POST['remember_me'];
        $token      = $_POST['token'];
        $redirect   = null;
        ...

    }
    public function genToken()
    {
       return md5(uniqid());
    }
```

Here is my view. (http://localhost/MVC/public/user/login)

```
<form id="login" method="post" action="http://localhost/MVC/public/user/loginAction" class="well">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= $data['token'] ?>" />
        <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="#">Forget the password?</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="1" checked /> Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="signin">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please try to avoid using superglobals in your methods. Better to pass them in if possible.

Comment: Could you give me an idea on how would I do this?

Comment: I would but I don't know how your users class is being called so I can't. Besides it's just a general rule of thumb. The general exception is if it's a controller class sometimes you can get away with it. You should consider doimg some input sanitation though.

Comment: And it's really hard for me to explain what is happening because I saw it in a video tutorial and I don't fully understand it, but here is my controller [user.php](https://pastebin.com/KyE4vNnv). My [Controller class](https://pastebin.com/KQxu4XJm) and my [App.php](https://pastebin.com/Q8KBKT71). I think that is enough to get the gist of what is going on.

Comment: Is it really going to benefit you if I review and make suggestions on code you don't fully understand? You should seek to understand the code first.

Comment: Of course, how else am I going to understand it? I just need to experiment more with the basic stuff - importing and exporting in and out of the database, etc.. This is why I am  building a login system.

Comment: I uploaded it to github if you want to see the entire code. https://github.com/Rakamishu/MVC

Comment: Why are you passing the view(input) directly to the model?I'm new to the MVC structure, but thanks to some great people here on stack I'v managed to expand my knowledge in the right way.If you wan't il write down the way how i structured my project and what I'm using thought the project.I haven't seen your whole code but form what i see i think that you fell of the path a bit.

Comment: Saw the code you posted on github, well you could benefit from a DiC and to use a mapper.I'l write it down if you will read it :D

Comment: Also what i see you are abstracting pdo here, you are just limiting your code here.Also you use lots of statics where they are not needed.You are missing namespaces here also.The controllers have potential to be good.

Comment: Yes, of course I will read it. I will appreciate your time :)

Comment: Imagine if you had a class, let's name it `Request`, which you could use to obtain HTTP-request related values, be those values `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_FILES`,`$_COOKIES`, HTTP headers and what not.. would that not be awesome? Now imagine you could do `request()->input('username');` from anywhere in your code. How great would that be? If you think something like that would be good, then it means I might have sparkled your imagination.

Comment: Yes this sounds great. I think I've seen it in codeigniter.

Answer (score 4):

### Superglobals

I cloned [your repo](https://github.com/Rakamishu/MVC) and it looks like you've already taken [my advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171915/passing-post-from-view-to-model-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment325787_171915) about [passing in the superglobals](https://github.com/Rakamishu/MVC/blob/master/app/models/Users.php#L18) instead of using them directly from your methods.

### Formatting

I would have also commented on the formatting but you've also significantly improved that since posting the question. Cheers!

### Commenting

The next good habit to get into is commenting, which s just as important as formatting and entirely lacking in this project. You should always put a short comment above every method explaining what it does, what parameters it takes and what it returns so you (and people maintaining the code in 
 the future) don't have to read the code to figure out what it does.

I see you're using NetBeans. I Like NB too. NB makes documenting your PHP and JS classes and functions very easy. I looked and I could not find any good documentation because I cannot remember what it's called, so I'll just explain the features as best I can.

#### Auto-commenting Pro Tip

Netbeans will actually do most of the work for you - place the cursor on the empty line just above the start of the function and type `/**` and hit the enter key. Netbeans will create the rest of the comment including the parameters and the return type (if there is one).

This is what Netbeans generated for your [loginAction](https://github.com/Rakamishu/MVC/blob/master/app/models/Users.php#L18) method.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type $username
 * @param type $password
 * @param type $rememberMe
 * @param type $token
 * @param type $redirect
 */
public function loginAction($username, $password, $rememberMe, $token, $redirect = null)
```

Now you just need to write a short description on the first blankk line and fill in the types (if NB wasn't able to guess them already). eg..

```
/**
 * Authenticate a user and start a session
 * @param String $username - The username of the user
 * @param String $password - The user's password
 * @param Boolean $rememberMe - Set a cookie?
 * @param String $token - Login token
 * @param String|Null $redirect - URL to redirect to
 */
public function loginAction($username, $password, $rememberMe, $token, $redirect = null)
```

Now, not only will this be easy to read and maintain, but NetBeans will actually parse these comments and show you what parameters are required when you start to type the method name:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE! The text below is how i understand MVC it doesn't have to be
>   completely right!

From what i have seen in your project you are missing the following things:

- Namespaces
- Bad project Organization
- Mixing logic
- You are abstracting PDO
- And a bunch of small thing...

MVC stands for Model View Controller, and we will pass each of thise and explain what which holds.

The main reason behind it is that we [Soc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) the project, and that we have an easier project organizaion.Tho it is not good for smaller projects since it can be an overkill.

---

We could separate the MVC architecture into two parts:

- **Presentation logic** (Router,Dispatcher,Bootstrap,Controllers,Views)
- **[Business logic/Domain logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic)** (Services,Mapper,Entities/Domain Objects...)

In this graph below it's explained how a well structured MVC project should look like:

[image]

Basically the router gets your input, the dispatcher gets the data thats being sent and sends it to the controller.
The controller calls the service, the service puts the data in an entity/domain object, constructs a mapper and sends that entity to that mapper.
The mapper communicates to the database.

---

Here are some references what to use:

- Slim 3 for routing + dispatcher
- Slim 3 for DiC(will be used to create the controllers and services in the bootstrap.It uses pimple)
- Yaml for some configuration stuff
- [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) for autoloading and much more

---

Here is a small kick start that will pass each of thise steps:

**Step 1:**

Create a project via composer and setup the following project structure

```
|-public
|      \index.php
|-src
|   \ProjectName
|              \Core
|              \Models
|              \Presentation
|              \Router
```

**Step 2:**

Setup Slim 3 DiC for easier controller and service loading.When it's up create the router it self.

Should look similar to this:

```
    //Setup Apps Controller
    $this->container['appsController'] = function () {
        $appController = new Controllers\AppsController(
            $this->container->get('appsService'),
            $this->container->get('logger'),
            $this->container->get('view')
        );
        return $appController;
    };
    //Setups Apps Service
    $this->container['appsService'] = function ($mapperFactory) {
        return new Service\Apps($this->container->get('mapperFactory'));
    };
```

Than in the router:

```
    //App Routes    
        $this->app->group(self::URL.'apps', function () {

            //Get App Packages
            $this->get('/{app_id}/packages', function ($request, $response, $args) {
                //Use Apps Controller Dependency
                $appsDependency = $this->get('appsController');
                //Call the Controllers Function
                $appsDependency->getAppPackages($request,$response, $args);
            });
...
```

**Step 3:**

Here is an example of how should the controller look like:

```
<?php

namespace Discus\Presentation\Controllers;

use Discus\Models\Service\Apps as Apps;

class AppsController
{

    protected $logger;
    protected $view;
    protected $apps;

    public function __construct(Apps $apps,$logger,$view)
    {
        $this->apps = $apps;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function getApps($request,$response, $args)
    {
        $getApps = $this->apps->getApps();
        //OutPut Json
        $this->view->renderJsonView(['data'=>$getApps],$response);
    }
```

From the controller you call the service:

**Step 4:**

Service example:

```
<?php

namespace Discus\Models\Service;

use Discus\Models\Entities\App as App;
use Discus\Core\Mapper\CanCreateMapper; 
use Discus\Models\Mapper as Mapper;

class Apps
{

    private $factory;

    public function __construct(CanCreateMapper $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    /**
    * Get All Apps 
    */
    public function getApps()
    {
        $apps = new App\App;

        $appsMapper = $this->factory->create(Mapper\Apps::class);
        $appsMapper->fetch($apps);

        return $apps->getApps();
    }
```

You build the mapper here that you will be using and you populate the entity data(if any), and you send it to the mapper.

**Step 5:**

The mapper:

```
class Apps extends DataMapper
{

    /**
    * Fetch All Apps
    */
    public function fetch(App\App $app)
    {   
        $sql = "SELECT 
                 id_app as id,
                 name,
                 package_name
                 FROM app ORDER BY id_app DESC";

        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();

        $data = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach($data as $data){
            $app->setApps($data);
        }

    }
```

See in this part that there is no abstraction to the PDO since there is no sense for abstracting it.

And her is how the **CanCreateMapper** looks like:

It's just an interface:

```
<?php

namespace Discus\Core\Mapper;

interface CanCreateMapper
{

    public function create(string $className);

}
```

Here is the DataMapper:

```
use PDO;

abstract class DataMapper
{

    protected $connection;
    protected $configuration;

    public function __construct(PDO $connection, array $configuration)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }

}
```

Here is the **MapperFactory**:

```
use PDO;

class MapperFactory implements CanCreateMapper
{
    private $connection;
    private $cache = [];
    private $configuration;

    public function __construct(PDO $connection, array $configuration)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->configuration = $configuration;
    }

    public function create(string $className): DataMapper
    {

        if (array_key_exists($className, $this->cache)) {
            return $this->cache[$className];
        }

        if (!class_exists($className)) {
            die("Mapper not found. Attempted to load '{$className}'.");
        }

        $instance = new $className($this->connection, $this->configuration);
        $this->cache[$className] = $instance;

        return $instance;
    }

}
```

It's a solid kick start for you and you will be able to learn a lot from this.

Also some you should check out PSR and Monolog.

Cheers :D

Comment: Wow, thank you for your detailed response! I will definitely take a better look at your examples but I think it's a little bit too overwhelming for me. Using Slim and whatnot. :D I am just trying to learn the basics of MVC and what handles what.

Comment: @user3628807 if you spend more time reading though the thing i wrote within 7 days you will understand all of it.I recommend that you start of with composer and slim.

Comment: Also if it was helpful accept the answer :D